# If $\cos^6(x)+\sin^6(x)=a+b\cos(4x)$. Find $ab$?

Tags: trigonometry

As after solving above equation, I get $1-3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$= $a+b\cos(4x)$.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: As a suggestion, try a few values for $x$.  That should give you an answer which you could then try to prove holds generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :** What happens if you replace $x$ by $0$ or $\pi/4$?

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\cos^6(x)+\sin^6(x)=\frac{1}{8}\left(5+3\cos(4x)\right)$$

Comment: Helpful? How? $ $

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$$4\sin^2x\cos^2x=(2\sin x\cos x)^2=(\sin2x)^2$$

$$\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$$

Comment: Helpful? How? $ $

Comment: @Did,  So, using the formulas mentioned in the post,  $$\cos^6x+\sin^6x=1-\dfrac{3\sin^22x}4=1-\dfrac38(1-\cos4x)=\cdots$$. Can you identify $a,b$ now?

Comment: Sorry but are you asking **me** if I can solve the exercise? Then either you are smoking some powerful stuff, or this is a typical, deliberate, try to deflect my remark that your answer is not adapted to (what one can guess from)  the OP's level of mathematical sophistication. Furthermore, if I were to solve this, I would definitely avoid the approach you suggest. In the end, what about you stopping to play word games and starting to make your answer useful? I know, the idea sounds crazy at first but...